# Main site url removed from google despite re-submitting it

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a site www.megalim.co.il, 
recently due to a version upgrade, I discovered that i have a robots.txt file that disallowed all Search engines.. my google ranking dropped , and I couldn't find the site's main page anymore
I changed the robots.txt file to one that allows all, and now the web master toolkit doesn't 
write me that the site is blocked from google.

I did this about 5 days ago, I've also fetched as google 
and submitted www.megalim.co.il to index with all related pages

but still, when i search this: "site:www.megalim.co.il"
i get a bunch of results from my site , but not the main page!

what else should I look for?

thanks!
Igal

Answer (score 1):

You don't see your main page because of your old robots.txt. 5 days is nothing for Google bots to re-index all your website.

Just wait a little and you will see your website fully indexed in Google results.

Answer (score 0):

Issue sorted out..
embarassing...
 apparently we (inexplicably) had a nofollow, noindex meta tag..
after a day we start reappearing in google

thanks :)